# Numpy: Appending a 2D array to 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

From my code a get a 2D dataframe which i converted to an array. My array is for example like this:

```
print(array.shape)
#(574,9)
```

In my code I want to collect multiple dataframes/arrays with same dimension and put them into a 3D array.

For that i created an array like this:

```
array1= array.reshape(1,array.shape[0],array.shape[1])
```

The thing now is I can only put the value 1 at first place. If i put something higher it says "cannot reshape array of size 5175 into shape (2,575,9)"

Also i dont really know how to write the command right in order to put a second 2D array on position 2 of my 3D array.

Hope you guys can help me out with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `reshape` can't change the total number of elements in the array.  It can be used to prepare your array for concatenation, but can't be used to create the 'space' for multiple arrays.  `np.stack([arr1, arr2, arr3, ...])` can make one 3d array from a list of 2d arrays.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. It worked for me using array1= np.stack((array,array)).